# Ajax - Send PHP value via ajax to another page

Tags: php, json, ajax

i have a form with a switch toggle and a input field named userid. 
When i switch the toggle all works fine and the active.php save the new status in the database. 
But now i want to have also the userid value to the active.php.
The var mode can i get in the active.php via

```
$mode=$_POST['mode'];
```

How can i send the userid also to active.php?

Any idea?
Thank you

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo 'toggle'.$c;?>" id="<?php echo 'toggle'.$c;?>" data-toggle="toggle" data-off="OFF" data-on="ON" checked>

 <input id="userid" name="userid" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $userid;?>">
```

This is the js code

```
$('#<?php echo 'toggle'.$c;?>').change(function(){
         var mode= $(this).prop('checked'),
 $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      dataType:'JSON',
      url:'active.php',
      data:'mode='+mode,
      success:function(data)
      {
        var data=eval(data);
        message=data.message;
        success=data.success;
        $("#heading").html(success);
        $("#body").html(message);

      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `&` to separate the two keys.

First of all, retrieve the  `userid` value

```
var userid = $('#userid').val();

data:'mode=' +mode+'&userid='+userid,
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax parameter, change the data attribute to look as follows:

```
data: 'mode='+mode + '&userid=' + $('#userid').val ()
```